# VST plugin and installing old VS extensions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to develop an VST plugin in **C#**. Looking around the internet there are not that many libraries in .NET that deal with VST plugins. The only thing I found is the VST.net library (https://vstnet.codeplex.com/). This thing hasn't been updated in a while.

The problem: I am having trouble setting it up the basic project. There are project templates for that project which are done for VS 2008/2010 which is **.vsi** file. I tried looking around for ways to open it in the latest VS (2017) but I was not successful.
Is there a way to open these in Visual Studio 2017 or should I have to install the older version of Visual Studio to make this work? Or if you have a suggestion for another library/extension that will help me with the development I would appreciate it.

Comments: I am aware that there is better support in **C++** for this type of thing but my additional problem is that I have a project in **C#** that I would like to use and not be forced to rewrite the entire code base.

Thank you in advance for looking into this issue.

Comment: Try using a sample as starting point. I just tested and the Clr4 sample project files open fine in VS2017. The Delay sample is practically the same as the audio project template. You can also just copy the project template source code from "\Support\VS Projects\CSharp\Plugin\Source"

Comment: Awesome, this will work out perfectly, I am really grateful.

Thank you for the quick answer and thank you for the work you did on this library.

Great job!

Comment: Thanks for kind words.